# visual studio lightswitch HTML : How do I place static text on a Browse screen

Tags: javascript, html, lightswitch-2013

I want to add some Help screens to my project but I don't know how to add static text to my screens. I created a browse screen called Help and opened the
Help.isml.js.
Does JavaScript have a way to output text to a screen ? or maybe place HTML?
I thought it would go here:

```js
myapp.Help.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    //put static text here ...
    //I tried this but it looks a bit strange
    document.write('<b>Getting Started</b>');
};
```

I found out I can use this:

```js
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
 myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```

I'm hoping to gather more suggestions. Thanks

Comment: How can I make this Hyperlink work: document.write('<a href="#">Return to Home Page</a>') where the Home page is /screens/Help.isml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst a multitude of different options are at your disposal, probably the best method is to simply add a local string property data item to your screen.

Taking this approach will ensure that the text becomes part of the screen's responsive layout and adapts to the browser windows size.

Adding this can be done by first selecting the "Add Data Item..." button at the top of the screen designer and specifying the property details as follows:

[image: Add Data Item]

This property can then be dragged into your screen's content tree as follows:

[image: Screen Designer]

Finally, you'll need to add the following code to your screen's created method (by selecting the "Write Code\General Methods\created" button at the top of the screen designer):

```
myapp.Browse.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.HelpProperty = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
};
```

This will result in the following Browse screen:

[image: Resulting Browse screen]

By working within the standard LightSwitch screen designer, this approach can be easily extended to implement a more traditional popup help system which would appear as follows:

[image: Example of popup help]

This is achieved by changing the control type of the HelpProperty from Text to Paragraph and then dragging it onto a new Popup.  The help can then be accessed by adding a Button to show this added Popup.

The following shows how the screen design should be structured for this type of approach:

[image: Screen designer showing popup approach]

And the following shows the settings for the added button:

[image: Add button settings]

If you'd like to build upon this technique, the following blog post contains a related example that provides an entry specific help system:

[Visual Studio LightSwitch Team Blog: Interacting with Content Items on the Screen with the LightSwitch API (Kevin Mehlhaff)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/02/18/interacting-with-content-items-on-the-screen-with-the-lightswitch-api-kevin-mehlhaff.aspx)

Comment: In light of your comment to @Filipe about navigation back after viewing the help, I've added some additional information regarding an extended popup help approach.

Comment: You have practically created an entire "How to:" article. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful and please click the tick to accept it as an answer and up vote if it was useful.  I've also added a final bit of information to the answer which covers an extension of the Popup technique to provide an entry driven help system.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.write("Your content here");`

Comment: yes very good suggestion but the user is left with a somewhat unfriendly looking screen with no intuitive way back to the app apart form the built in "Back" arrow in the browser. Thanks

Comment: But you did answer the question Thanks

Answer (score 1):

an alternative option with the text box that @ChrisCook has created is

```
element.innerText = "Text Here";
```

with the element commands you can alter the font size, colour and weight...

examples:

```
myapp.TestScreen.Status_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
   element.innerText = "Text Here";
   element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
   element.style.fontSize = "18px";
   element.style.color = "blue";
};
```

this can be used on a table to alter text also, such as values < 0 can be red and values greater than 0 can be green

Answer (score 0):

Since the Lightswitch blog got wiped out, here's a repost of the snippet that was originally suggested by Kevin Mehlhaff:

```
// Adds description help to each content item   
myapp.AddEditCustomer.columns_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {   
    // Look for content items with type either 'details' (a navigation property)    
    // or 'value' (non-relationship properties)    
    var contentItemTypes = [];   
    contentItemTypes.push(msls.ContentItemKind.details);   
    contentItemTypes.push(msls.ContentItemKind.value);   
    // Find these content items starting from the children of the 'columns' content item    
    var matchingContentItems = findMatchingContentItems(contentItemTypes, contentItem);   
    // Find all LABEL elements that are descendants of the parent element rendering the    
    // 'columns' content item    
    var $matchingElements = $(element).find("label");   
    $.each($matchingElements, function (index) {   
        // Set the LABEL element to float left    
        $(this).css("float", "left");   
        // Create a new A element that will display the '?' link    
        var $help = $("<a href='#'>?</a>");   
        $help.css({ "cursor": "pointer", "display": "block", "float": "right" });   
        var correspondingContentItem = matchingContentItems[index];   
        // Add a click event handler to display the content item description    
        $help.on('click', function (e) {   
            e.preventDefault();   
            contentItem.screen.HelpText = correspondingContentItem.description;   
            contentItem.screen.showPopup('Help');   
        });   
        // Insert the help element as a sibling after the LABEL element    
        $(this).after($help);   
    });   
};    
function findMatchingContentItems(arrayOfTypes, parentContentItem) {   
    var matches = [];   
    // Return an empty array if no children to look at    
    if (parentContentItem.children.length == 0) {   
        return matches;   
    }   
    $.each(parentContentItem.children, function (i, contentItem) {   
        $.each(arrayOfTypes, function (j, type) {   
            if (contentItem.kind == type) {   
                matches.push(contentItem);   
            }   
        });   
        // Check the child's children for matches    
        matches = matches.concat(findMatchingContentItems(arrayOfTypes, contentItem));   
    });   
    return matches;   
};
```